# DOM manipulation on radio checked with KockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

What I'm trying to achieve:
When radio button is selected, trigger double click on element.

Current solution:

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="checked: isChecked, resetDefault"/>
<script>
var ProfileManager = function(){
    self.resetDefault = ko.observable();
    self.resetDefault.subscribe(function() {
        jQuery('#test').trigger('click').trigger('click');
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ProfileManager());
```

The issue is that it's not triggering on check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When radio button is selected, trigger double click on element

I can't think of a reason why you'd want to do this, so I'll just focus on the first part: triggering a method when the button gets checked.

Your binding syntax, `checked: isChecked, resetDefault`, doesn't do what you think it does. `resetDefault` appears after the `,` and is therefore seen as a binding key. I.e.: you're attempting to apply a binding *named* `resetDefault` (which probably does not exist) with an empty value accessor. The `checked` binding is correctly configured in the view, but you forgot to add the `isChecked` property to your viewmodel.

Here's how to fix it:

```js
var ProfileManager = function() {
  self.isChecked = ko.observable(false);
  self.isChecked.subscribe(function(isChecked) {
    if (isChecked)
      console.log("selected");
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ProfileManager());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" data-bind="checked: isChecked" />
```